# Difference between "yield" of Tornado and "yield from" of asyncio in mechanism?

Tags: python, generator, tornado, yield

In Tornado, we usually write the following code to call a function asynchronously:

```
class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

    @tornado.gen.coroutine
    def post(self):
        ...
        yield self.handleRequest(foo)
        ...

    @tornado.gen.coroutine
    def handleRequest(self, foo):
        ...
```

But in asyncio (will be shipped with Python 3.4, can be installed from pip for Python 3.3), we use `yield from` to achieve the same thing:

```
@asyncio.coroutine
def myPostHandler():
    ...
    yield from handleRequest(foo)
    ...


@asyncio.coroutine
def handleRequest(foo)
    ...
```

Seeing from the code, the difference is `yield` and `yield from`. However the former `handleRequest(foo)` returns a `tornado.concurrent.Future` object, the latter returns a `generator` object.

My question is, what is the difference between the two things in mechanism? How is the control flow? And who calls the actual `handleRequest` and retrieves its returning value?

Append: I have basic knowledge of Python generators and iterators. I wanted to understand what Tornado and asyncio achieved by using these, and what is the difference between those two mechanisms.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There is a huge difference between the two. `yield from` takes another generator and continues yielding from that generator instead (delegating responsibility, as it were). `yield` just yields **one** value.

In other words, `yield from`, in the simplest case, could be replaced by:

```
for value in self.handleRequest(foo):
    yield value
```

If you replaced a `yield from <expression>` line with `yield <expression>` you'd return the whole generator to the caller, not the values that generator produces.

The `yield from` syntax was only introduced in Python 3.3, see [PEP 380: Syntax for Delegating to a Subgenerator](http://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html#pep-380-syntax-for-delegating-to-a-subgenerator). Tornado supports Python versions 2.6, 2.7 and 3.2 in addition to Python 3.3, so it cannot rely on the `yield from` syntax being available. `asyncio`, on the other hand, being a core Python library added in 3.4, can fully rely on the `yield from` generator delegation syntax being available.

As a result, Tornado will have to post-process values yielded from a `@tornado.gen.coroutine` generator to detect that a `tornado.concurrent.Future` object was yielded; the `@asyncio.coroutine` code handling can be much simpler. And indeed the [Tornado `Runner.run()` method](https://github.com/facebook/tornado/blob/c9af9a7224b1f42e91ad88b0a3f8f10478584b0a/tornado/gen.py#L507) does explicit type checks to handle delegated tasks.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. But my question is not related to `yield` itself. I am concerned about what Tornado and asyncio achieved by using `yield` and `yield from`.

Comment: @StarBrilliant: They achieve deferring the task until later; generators can be paused so that the event loop can pass control to another generator.

Comment: @StarBrilliant: The coroutine runner will then loop through the active coroutines and give each a chance to execute. A coroutine that needs to wait for network resources can then just immediately yield again to allow control to pass to other coroutines that perhaps do not have to wait.

Comment: @StarBrilliant: But your question appeared to be about the syntax difference; `yield from` makes the runner code simpler; `tornado` has to use explicit wrappers to handle delegation, `asyncio` can rely on the syntax to take care of delegation instead.

Comment: Sorry about my unclear language expression. I am very satisfied with your answer now. Thank you a lot.

Comment: In addition to making the runner simpler, `yield from` is also faster and tends to result in better stack traces when there is an error.  On the other hand, Tornado's use of `yield` provides better interoperability between coroutines and non-coroutines (including both asynchronous logic with explicit callbacks and threaded executors).